# Best way to apply code to 24 similar datasets?

Tags: r

I have a 24 datasets that each have one factor and one response. I have written code to subset the 93 entries into 3 categories, but I'm not sure what the most efficient way there is to run this code for all 24 of my datasets. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Here's the data I'm working with.

```
 dput(head(data)) 
structure(list(run.size.percentage = structure(c(2L, 13L, 24L, 
35L, 46L, 57L), .Label = c(",2000,", "1,0.375,0.013", "10,0.868,0.11", 
"11,0.953,0.12", "12,1.047,0.12", "13,1.149,0.13", "14,1.261,0.14", 
"15,1.385,0.14", "16,1.520,0.15", "17,1.668,0.15", "18,1.832,0.16", 
"19,2.011,0.17", "2,0.412,0.023", "20,2.207,0.17", "21,2.423,0.18", 
"22,2.660,0.19", "23,2.920,0.20", "24,3.205,0.21", "25,3.519,0.22", 
"26,3.863,0.24", "27,4.240,0.25", "28,4.655,0.26", "29,5.110,0.28", 
"3,0.452,0.034", "30,5.610,0.30", "31,6.158,0.31", "32,6.760,0.33", 
"33,7.421,0.35", "34,8.147,0.37", "35,8.943,0.39", "36,9.817,0.42", 
"37,10.78,0.45", "38,11.83,0.47", "39,12.99,0.50", "4,0.496,0.049", 
"40,14.26,0.53", "41,15.65,0.56", "42,17.18,0.58", "43,18.86,0.59", 
"44,20.70,0.59", "45,22.73,0.58", "46,24.95,0.55", "47,27.39,0.52", 
"48,30.07,0.49", "49,33.01,0.46", "5,0.545,0.061", "50,36.24,0.45", 
"51,39.78,0.45", "52,43.67,0.45", "53,47.94,0.44", "54,52.62,0.42", 
"55,57.77,0.38", "56,63.41,0.35", "57,69.61,0.32", "58,76.42,0.31", 
"59,83.89,0.33", "6,0.598,0.072", "60,92.09,0.36", "61,101.1,0.42", 
"62,111.0,0.49", "63,121.8,0.59", "64,133.7,0.74", "65,146.8,0.94", 
"66,161.2,1.19", "67,176.9,1.49", "68,194.2,1.82", "69,213.2,2.18", 
"7,0.656,0.083", "70,234.1,2.55", "71,256.9,2.94", "72,282.1,3.34", 
"73,309.6,3.78", "74,339.9,4.25", "75,373.1,4.73", "76,409.6,5.20", 
"77,449.7,5.60", "78,493.6,5.87", "79,541.9,5.93", "8,0.721,0.093", 
"80,594.9,5.77", "81,653.0,5.37", "82,716.8,4.77", "83,786.9,4.03", 
"84,863.9,3.21", "85,948.3,2.36", "86,1041,1.55", "87,1143,0.81", 
"88,1255,0.30", "89,1377,0.056", "9,0.791,0.10", "90,1512,0.0044", 
"91,1660,0", "92,1822,0"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's the code that worked for each dataset.

```
data2 <- tidyr::separate(names(data), unlist(strsplit(names(data), "\\.")), ",", data=data)

group1 <- data2 %>% filter(size <= 2)
group2 <- data2 %>% filter(size > 2 & size <= 50)
group3 <- data2 %>% filter(size > 50 & size <= 2000)

sum(as.numeric(group1$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
sum(as.numeric(group2$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
sum(as.numeric(group3$percentage), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: You could probably make a function out of your code and use ``apply()`` or a ``for loop``.

Answer (score 0):

Put your dataframes in a list and use `lapply`. Used `cut` to create the needed size groups. Also added `convert = TRUE` arg to `separate` to convert numbers into numeric -

```
df_list <- list(df, df) # creating a dummy list with same df

lapply(df_list, function(x) {
  separate(names(df), unlist(strsplit(names(df), "\\.")), ",",
           data = df, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(group = cut(size, breaks = c(0,2,50,2000,Inf))) %>% 
    summarise(percentage = sum(percentage))
})

# every list element is your desired output df

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  group percentage
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 (0,2]      0.252

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  group percentage
  <fct>      <dbl>
1 (0,2]      0.252
```